# "JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: unavailable " in Geoserver

Tags: java, gdal, geoserver

I'm trying to get GDAL extensions to work in a Geoserver 2.23.2
Upon starting Geoserver, I can see that GDAL has been enabled but not available.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WWZG.jpg)
[Server status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHq0o.jpg)

It is giving this error-

```
JNI GDAL Wrapper Version: unavailable

java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.19.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python311\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_201;C:\Program Files\geoserver\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Myprograms\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251;;.
```

I am using java 11 and Geoserver version 2.23.2 in windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer is reporting that it can't find the JNI GDAL wrapper and dlls on your `java.library.path` - where did you install GDAL?

You need to correctly set that variable - see the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html#windows-packages-and-setup) for more details.